# How to change copyright font color

Tags: magento2

I can't figure out how to change the font color of the copyright text in the footer. I am leaning using for a school project and am editing in the theme.less.
Any idea? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired outcome by following these steps to insert CSS into the footer's copyright section using admin penal.

- Go to "`Content" -> "Design" -> "Configuration`" from the main menu.
- Select the configuration scope for which you want to change the copyright font color (e.g., Global, Main Website, Main Store, etc.).
- In the "`Footer" section`, expand and got the "`Miscellaneous HTML`" field In this field add below CSS for change font colour(You can also add your custom css for footer).

---

```
<style>
body{
    .copyright {
           color: #FF0000; /* Replace #FF0000 with the desired font color code */
    }
}
</style>
```

- Save the configuration.
- Clear cache and check the output